# Find partial sums of $\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{1}{16}-\frac{3}{32}-\frac{1}{32}+ \,\,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the sum of the first $2n-1$ and $2n-2$ terms of the series 
>   $$\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{1}{16}-\frac{3}{32}-\frac{1}{32}+ \,\,...$$

By looking at the first partial sums I got to formula $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3 \cdot 2^{n+1}}$ for the first $2n-1$ terms and $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3 \cdot 2^{n-2}}$ for the first $2n-2$ terms
However, I can't prove this by induction.

Comment: You should write this as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot(3+1)}{2^{n+1}}$ may be it will become clearer.

Comment: Add first and second terms, third and fourth terms etc to form a new series. It is easy to find its sum and then subtract a term to get your desired sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in the commentary section we can write this sum as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}\cdot4}{2^{k+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^{k-1}}. $$

Now, if we need to know partial sum of order $2n-2$ it's similar as writing our sum from $k=1$ to $n-1$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$ And we get:

Case $n$ is even:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^{k-1}}=1-1/2+1/4 + \dots +\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}=\frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+1)$$

Case $n$ is odd:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^{k-1}}=1-1/2+1/4 + \dots -\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}=\frac{2}{3}(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}) $$

And to find partial sum of order $2n-1$ we just need to add one more element which looks like $\pm \frac{3}{2^{n-1}}$, plus or minus depends on $n$ (plus for odd or minus for even) i think you can figure it from here.

Comment: I think the next element in the second sum is $\pm \frac{3}{2^{n+1}}$ instead of $\pm \frac{3}{2^{n}}$. Thanks!

Comment: I messed up a little bit by this factors, but fixed in now.